# How to get and set text in react-native from java

Tags: java, android, react-native

I have a few questions about react-native. I'm developing a calculator. In the calculator there are 2 text-view, responsible for entering the input-line (input is from the buttons) and for displaying the result. I need to press the "=" button to transfer the input-line to the android-module, parse this string and return the numeric result to text-view with the result in result-view. How can I do that?

I read that I need to create a native module, but did not understand how to get the text from the js. And as I still understood, I need a callback to set the text in the view for the result.

My code:

```
      <View style={{backgroundColor:'#282828',height:50}}> 
        <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center'}}>
            <Text style={[styles.resultText,{fontSize:(30-(this.state.result.toString().length))}]}> 
              {this.state.result}
            </Text> //It's a result text-view
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'column',justifyContent:'flex-end'}}>
        <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'#494949'}}>
          <View style={{flex:1,alignItems:'center',flexDirection:'row'}}>
              <Text style={styles.formulaText}>
                {this.state.formula}
              </Text> //It's a input text-view
          </View>
        </View>//Below is another code
<Button  style={styles.equalButton} titleStyle = {styles.titleOperationStyle} onPress={this.onPressSubmitResult} title="="/>//Equals button
```

Thank you in advance.
P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: What do you think that you have to call from native module. You can do this task on react-native side easily.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to read more about the native modules.

Comment: I just need to use the native module. I would gladly do this on js, but I can not.

Comment: I have such a technical assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to call getText setText from Native. All of what you want can be done by React-Native. Code in Js files itself, do your calculations there, update the state and show you result in a Text!